# Polite word or short phrase that means "this isn't a high enough priority for us to work on now"

Tags: phrase-requests, politeness

I'm not looking for a technical term, but a more polite way of saying that the user's request is a lower priority and we may or may not get to it once higher priority issues are cleared out.  The company owner and top management will see these statuses, so they shouldn't be slang.

For purposes of understanding what I am looking for, here are some other "statuses" I am using (but can be changed to match the tone of this status if necessary):

- New
- Being Investigated
- Being Worked
- Ready for Testing
- Completed

If necessary, we may end up with multiple statuses, one which indicates that it should be worked soon, and one or more others which indicate that it may be awhile or it may never actually get done.

I've looked at various websites and considered terms like

- queued (promises completion, and may or may not be easily known to Americans)
- waiting for resources (true, but very technical)
- parked (to much slang)
- pending (pending what?)

But none of them really convey the politeness of the possibility that we may or may not get to this in the near future.

Feel free to ask for any clarifications, or to edit this to make it more appropriate for this site (I usually posted on Stack Overflow, but since I don't want a technical term, I thought all of you would do a better job of it).

UPDATE: added the adjective "short" to the title because that is what I really want.

Comment: Would the following do? *This matter is not urgent enough* or *we're tending to more serious matters*

Comment: @vickyace You got the meaning, but I'd like it shorter.  I'm adding the adjective "short" to the title (because while I give examples in the question body, but I should have asked for a word or short phrase).  Thanks for trying, though, as it pointed out my title could have been better.

Comment: What about "Low Priority"? It is  concise and generally carries the connotation that it will not happen until the priority is raised.

Comment: @JosiahDaniels The problem with "Low Priority" is that it could be a higher priority then "Low" but still may be stuck in the queue for awhile due to having really high priority items being worked.  "Lower Priority" is a bit more accurate, but lower than what?  It's also not as polite as I would prefer.

Comment: The phrases that reverberates in most places do not hint that someone's  problem or issue is low priority because of feelings. Phrases like *we're short staffed* *pressed for time* *really busy* *doing everything we can* are used instead. The suggestion by @JosiahDaniels has a fair point. It is laconic and may serve well for some people. But I'll look for more, maybe a word.

Comment: @vickyace While I don't want to be complaining to the higher ups that we are short staffed, I do like the concept that "we're busy right now, please be patient" rather than "you need to get this bumped this to a higher priority".  We don't want to encourage playing the "everything is highest priority" game ("Yes, but which is the highest of the highest priorities?")

Comment: Unless you're talking about emergency or perhaps medical work, you're facing an up-hill battle on appearing to be polite when you're trying to tell someone that their job is of such low priority that all of your staff have 'better' things to do. In that case, you're probably better off showing them objectively where they stand (e.g. "You're 25th in the queue. The wait time is currently 30 minutes.").

Comment: What about "Currently low priority" or "Queued for investigation: low priority" - both implying that the priority *may* change in the future.

Comment: You are indeed looking for a vague term like your own queued or pending. The advantage is they do not define why or when, and both words are common in American IT. They also avoid the obvious "But why is it waiting or unassigned?"

Comment: Years ago, a poster circulated of "Sylvester the Cat" asking "Would you mind very much if I asked you to take your silly little problem down the hall?"

Comment: ......Received.

Comment: I like pending to be honest, it suggests that it is being passed through a process before it is worked on. Could you just add something to that? "Your request has been allocated a priority and is now pending"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consider ***deferred***.

ODO:

> **[defer](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/defer)**
>   *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   **1** Put off (an action or event) to a later time; postpone.
>
> ‘Laois County Council have deferred all meetings of Laois County
>   Council until further notice.’

Also, ***under consideration***.

dictionary.com:

> **[under consideration](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/under-consideration)**
>   Being thought about or discussed, *as in* Your application is under consideration; we'll let you know next week.

Comment: Deferred isn't bad.  I was hoping for something a little more polite / less harsh though.

Answer (score 2):

That change is on our on the **product backlog**.

This term is part of [Agile](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) terminology, and is no longer niche or technical.

> What is a **product backlog**?
> A product backlog is a prioritized list of work for the development team that is derived from the roadmap and its requirements. The most important items are shown at the top of the product backlog so the team knows what to deliver first. The development team doesn't work through the backlog at the product owner's pace and the product owner isn't pushing work to the development team. Instead, the development team pulls work from the product backlog as there is capacity for it, either continually (kanban) or by iteration (scrum).
>
> - https://www.atlassian.com/agile/backlogs